# how fix error AndroidManifest.xml after open for edit

Tags: flutter, firebase, sha1

after open for edit  for signing report in dradle file or gradlew to get sha-1
for connect with Firebase

i get alot of error and cant build the app

Please check C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects\learn2\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml for errors. No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm64. Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml? Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.

Comment: maybe you have accidentally edited something from your androidManifest file that makes it uncompilable. the easiest thing to do is to delete your android manifest file or even the entire android directory and from the root of your project run `flutter create .` this will recreate all the missing files from your project.

Comment: that  what i get from flutter create 

No option specified for the output directory.
Create a new Flutter project.

If run on a project that already exists, this will repair the project, recreating any files that are missing.

and Global options: for command what i thould use 

Usage: flutter create <output directory>

-h, --help
--[no-]pub 
--[no-]offline
--[no-]overwrite
--description
--org
--project-name
--android-language

Comment: you need to be in your project root directory when running flutter create

Comment: i am in root  

C:\nady\pro\learn1>

or that is not right ?

Comment: `C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects\learn2`  this is the root as i can see from your post

Comment: i delete the last project > and make other one in other root as test 

all is happend to connect firebase <

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.